# Nebular throwing 'Nb-action' is not a known element:' error?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement nebular in my work so I am following [this](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/layout/overview#nblayoutcolumncomponent) Nebular tutorial for work out.

I have installed nebular. And it is working fine with `<nb-layout>` `<nb-header>` but when I am using `<nb-actions>` or `<nb-menu>` it is throwing the following error

```
compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'nb-action' is not a known element:
1. If 'nb-action' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nb-action' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this
```

I do not know what is the issue. How to fix it?

side.html

```
<nb-layout>      
    <nb-layout-header subheader>
        <nb-actions>
        <nb-action icon="nb-home"></nb-action>
        <nb-action icon="nb-search"></nb-action>
        <nb-action icon="nb-edit"></nb-action>
        </nb-actions>
    </nb-layout-header>

</nb-layout>
```

side.ts  //component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector:"sidebar",
    templateUrl:"./side.html",
    styleUrls:["side.css"]
})
export class sideComponent{


}
```

sbar.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NbSidebarModule, NbLayoutModule, NbSidebarService } from '@nebular/theme';
import {sideComponent} from "./sidecomp/side";

const routes: Routes = [{path:"sidebar",component:sideComponent}]


@NgModule({
  declarations:[
    sideComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),    
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbLayoutModule

  ],
  providers:[NbSidebarService],
  exports:[sideComponent]
})
export class SbarModule { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have imported **NbLayoutModule**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbLayoutModule
 ]
```

Also your errors says nb-action, instead it should be **`nb-actions`**, make sure you don thave a typo

**EDIT**

You need to import `NbActionsModule` as well. Check the code **[`here`](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/8ef741268f0eab8821e0dd301e98ae58082afd1d/src/playground/playground.module.ts)**

Comment: Yes I am importing the NbLayoutModule but still I am facing the issue. I edited my code. Please take a look on it

Answer (score 0):

you have to import NbLayoutModule in your App module as well as any child module.

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
      // ...
    NbLayoutModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your child module import as

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
      // ...
    NbLayoutModule,
  ],
})
export class PageModule { }
```

Comment: Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NbLayoutModule'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation just use button

[button](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/button/examples#nbbuttoncomponent)

```html
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>Button</nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body class="example-items-rows">
    <button nbButton>Active</button>
    <button nbButton disabled>Disabled</button>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Answer (score -1):

Import NbActionsModule  module. it will work